# mysql workbench - table could not fetched with root account all privileges

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I user mysql workbench and root account to connect to database. Connection is successful, but it has error :

> "Table could not be fetched".

When i connect to server with ssh count and connect mysql also with root account => success. Then i show all tables is show ok. I also checked root account has all privileges.

Can you help me what's wrong ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench do you use? Is it the latest one? Also, which version is your server?

Comment: How did you solve it? I have a similar problem , where Navicat sees the database fine, but Workbench says it can't fetch the tables.

Comment: I found that my server over. :)